# How to efficiently perform server queries?

Tags: android, performance

I want to implement an article viewer with the help of tabs. Basically each tab will correspond to an article category (e.g. Sports, News and so on) and will contain a list underneath with all the available articles (much like the google play store implementation in the Movies>Top Selling or Music>Top Albums/New Releases).

The problem is that those articles will be pulled from a server and the server's query protocol is... impractical at best. It supports two kinds of queries. One that will result in a json file of the category, which is basically a list of the article titles, authors and id's and the other that will result in another json file with article-specific data (Author, Header, Body, et.c.).

My question is the following:

The way I see it, there are 5 categories, each containing 5 articles, so that means that I will possibly have to query the server 30 times to first get the data from the category-wide query to populate the listViews and each time a list item (i.e. an article) is being clicked, I'll have to query the server again for the article itself. Let alone the fact that I will have to have 10 SQLite tables  on the device (5 for category data and another 5 which actually contain the articles).

This all sounds wildly inefficient to me, so does anyone have a better idea of implementing this?

Comment: Short answer: use Volley

Comment: Could you please elaborate or at least give me a couple of other searchwords to pair with "Volley"?

Comment: @AutomEng http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: This seems like a perfectly normal API, btw. I'm not sure why you wouldn't have at most two tables, one for categories, and one for articles.

Comment: I don't get why actually should you have 10 SQLite tables for articles, when you can have one table with columns: ID (I don't know if you have it, but it's better to have), Category, Title, Text, etc. updated on demand. So when you receive a category response, you just create entry with prefilled fields that are available. Then as soon as you request the contents of the article, you just update the entry. And voila you have only one table instead of 10

Comment: @Chaosit if I understand correctly, you mean create an aggregate table and populate it at different times?

Comment: @AutomEng correct, as I've understood your first request provides you with initial data on the contents of category (which articles are located in it), and then in order to get data on each article you perform another request to get all information relevant to specific article. If my vision is correct, then after the first request you create entries in the table with all available fields filled, then as you request details you just have to update corresponding entry filling empty fields.

Comment: @Chaosit, Dave Newton thanks guys, I'll try these approaches and see what happens, although I'm not that comfortable with databases in android yet.

Comment: @AutomEng, for these purposes I would suggest using ORMLite: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android it provides a very convenient mechanism of interacting with databases, and you don't have to writ queries manually

Comment: @Chaosit Isn't SQLiteOpenHelper convenient? Also, because the database is going to be updated on demand it should not contain "NOT NULL" constraints, isn't that right?